# Show that [0, 1) with the induced topology from R is a Polish space.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

It's easy to see that the space is separable because $Q \cap [a,b)$ is a countably dense subset of $[a,b)$, but I can't figure out a way to show that it's completely metrizable.  I know this means that there exists a metric $d$ on $[a,b)$ such that $([a,b), d)$ is complete.  This means that there exists a metric such that every Cauchy sequence in $[a,b)$ has a convergent point in $[a,b)$.  I can't figure out how to make a metric that would do this.  I've tried thinking about homeomorphisms because of the preservation of completely metrizable spaces but that doesn't seem to lead anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two reasonable approaches. One is to construct a complete metric equivalent to the usual one; I’ll get to that in a moment. The other is to prove the [result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_set#Properties) that a $G_\delta$ set in a complete metric space is completely metrizable; since $[0,1)$ is certainly a $G_\delta$ in $\Bbb R$, that theorem yields the desired result.

To get a complete metric, you want to stretch $[0,1)$ out to the right, so that there are no Cauchy sequences piling up at $1$. A small modification of the tangent function mapping $[0,1)$ onto $[0,\rightarrow)$ will do the trick. (In case it isn’t clear, $[0,\rightarrow)$ is another standard notation for $[0,\infty)$.)